# How can I get rid of MacKeeper Helper on my mac's activity monitor

Tags: macos, malware

I have tried to quit, force quit and so many more things in Terminal and all over the place but it's still there.

Comment: Check: `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`, `/Library/LaunchAgents`, `~/Library/LaunchAgents` directories. If there's something related to **MacKeeper** delete it and kill the process again.

Answer (score -1):

There is an article on deleting MacKeeper in the Feb issue of MacWorld.

This suggests starting from Applications, Quit, then move MacKeeper.app to Trash.

There was more if it persists.